# Make bootstrap page full screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to make this .html page full screen on my browser, but when I achieve it in my screen Laptop, it's still not full screen in my other screen which is larger.

This template is from bootstrap web site.

[image]

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 550px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What full screen `width` `height` or both??

Comment: try making your html height - 100vh, i think your screen height/width is larger than the content you have coded.

Comment: @Turnip - if this can be reopened, I would like to add another solution---in the event that the other solution does not work (and of course, you can close it as soon as my solution is in)